# kotlin "when" gets compile error with "startWith"

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors

I am noob to Kotlin (though I have a lot of experience in other languages like java).  I'm trying to write some code in Kotlin and don't understand why the following doesn't compile.

```
private fun test(inpStr : String) =
        when (inpStr) {
            "bill" -> "harry"
            startsWith "john" -> "john"
            else -> inpStr
        }
```

The following does compile:

```
private fun test2(inpStr : String) =
        when {
            inpStr == "bill" -> "harry"
            inpStr.startsWith("john") -> "john"
            else -> inpStr
        }
```

Based on my understanding of "when", I would have thought they would both compile and be equivalent.  The error message I get is on the "startsWith" line:

```
 Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun File.startsWith(other: File): Boolean defined in kotlin.io
public fun File.startsWith(other: String): Boolean defined in kotlin.io
public fun CharSequence.startsWith(char: Char, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
public fun CharSequence.startsWith(prefix: CharSequence, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
public fun CharSequence.startsWith(prefix: CharSequence, startIndex: Int, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
public fun String.startsWith(prefix: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`when (inpStr)` has special rules for `(!)is ...`, `(!)in ...` and `else`.

`startsWith "john"` is not one of these, so it's assumed to be a complete expression just like `"bill"`; it would be calculated and then compared with `inpString`. 
There's no transformation into `inpStr.startsWith("john")` as you assumed.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't understand that "is" and "in" are special.  I thought they were just examples of the kind of thing you could do.  Would have been nice if it had worked the way I thought.  But, we work with what we have.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If this answers your question sufficiently, consider accepting it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Wasn't sure how to do that.  Figured it out :)

Comment: Would anyone care to post what's the solution aka what to do?

Comment: @Damercy It's under "The following does compile" in the question.